# What is a non-religious word for an apocalyptic event?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a noun which describes some sort of apocalyptic or world-ending event, but does not have the religious baggage of words like *apocalypse*.

Comment: Catastrophe? Cataclysm? Apocalypse does not necessarily have religious connotations.

Comment: @luke OK on the first two, but beg to differ on apocalypse. It comes from Greek for *revelation* and refers to a biblical text. See [this source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=apocalypse)

Comment: [Fifth definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apocalypse?s=t). I see where you're coming from, but it is not necessarily religious.

Comment: @luke While the word may often be used without intending a religious connotation, OP is trying to avoid the religious *baggage* that some readers may bring to the term.

Comment: Whatever happened to English?

Comment: If there is ever a time for people to "get religion" it will be when the world is about to end.

Answer (score 3):

*TEOTWAWKI* - *the end of the world as we know it*

Answer (score 1):

The [singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity).  The [event horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon).

Answer (score 1):

The traditional "sciencespeak" for this is "Extinction scale event".